# create dynamic sub domain using PHP & htaccess in xampp localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to create dynamic subdomain using PHP and htaccess in xampp localhost
i stored sub domain name in mysql but i wanna check like following in xampp localhost in window platform

means 
http://example.com/subdomain?=alabaster

i want like this 
http://alabaster.example.com
by php mysql in localhost xampp 
will u explain it step by step

how to run it localhost xampp window

advance thanx

Comment: Did you really meant `http://example.com/subdomain?=alabaster` or is this a typo and you meant `http://example.com/?subdomain=alabaster` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^subdomain=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%1.example.com?  [L,R=301]
```

Those links might help you :

- [Apache wiki page on how to manipulate the Query String](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)
- [Test your apache htaccess files online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)